# Being able to change spreadsheet in VLOOKUP macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that does a VLOOKUP from a specific excel spreadsheet, it is current hard-coded into the macro. I was wondering if there is a way to make it so the specific excel spreadsheet can change (i.e. prompts me to select a spreadsheet then the VLOOKUP uses the new spreadsheet instead of the hard-coded one)?

Here is a portion of the code which shows the hard-coded file:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'[Z401 Toyota 25 Nov 16.xlsx]MPF_D_PRI_RSK_20161122_092440_W'!C9:C10,2,0)"
```

I'd like the filename in there to be interchangeable. Is this possible somehow through a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim fName As String

fName = "Z401 Toyota 25 Nov 16.xlsx"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-11],'[" & fName & _
                          "]MPF_D_PRI_RSK_20161122_092440_W'!C9:C10,2,0)"
```

Comment: Is there a way for the filename to not be in the macro so when I run the macro it asks me to choose which file I want to use?

Comment: You can use `Application.GetOpenFileName()` for that.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh710200(v=office.14).aspx